# Need help identifying weird serial protocol

Tags: i2c, embedded, synchronous, serial-bus

[image]

I am trying to decode an embedded serial protocol. The device is a  wired remote control for a crane. The controls are obsolete. I'm trying to design a new replacement one.

There are a few buttons and a display on the remote.

Poking around I found one seemingly clock signal and one seemingly data line.

It does look a bit like I2C but there are 35 pulses and I can't really line up a typical I2C packet. On both ends the lines are connected to timer ports, not  a com port on the microcontroller.

It would be unlikely to me that its a fully custom implementation of a protocol, my guess is it looks like something, I just don't know what.

Comment: This does not look like any communication protocol per ce. The bottom line seems to simply have pulse trains that are being enabled and disabled at times. Could be some encoder pulses? Could be i2C clock of course, but if the top line is SDA it won't make much sense too. What are the timings here?

Comment: The pulses are at a steady 5kHz, the spacing is also constant at about 1 msec. between trains. There are no encoders in the system so I would be surprised if it were encoder pulses. It would be the hypothetical SDA, but I agree it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I'd suggest confirming this "data" with a 'scope. Just to make sure this is really the data you are seeing. I'd bet it *is* a custom protocol. If you can capture the pulses and recreate them with your microcontroller, then it may be moot to decode them.

Comment: The two signals might be unrelated to each other as well.

Comment: If it was I2C you'd expect to see each burst of clock pulses framed with a start and a stop condition., but these are conspicuously missing. It looks to me more like a synchronous serial scheme, perhaps using the 1mSec break as a framing marker.

Comment: @brhans There "data" line is too "flat" for a serial protocol if you ask me.

Comment: make an assuption that the bottom trace is a clock signal and that the rising edge is used ... then prove or disprove the assumption

Comment: how many buttons are on the control box? ... how many segments are on the display? ... there may be a 1:1 correpondence between hardware and data

Comment: Try again with different buttons pressed and also try two buttons pressed at the same time.  I will take a SWAG and assume the top pattern will be different with each button. The bottom I would guess is a clock that times the signal and the buttons will change state of the top trace at various points, a repeatable pattern.

Comment: If it _is_ I2C then whoever designed it was a muppet, since you cannot use that for wired crane controls - doing so is wildly illegal. What are the voltages? Are you sure this is voltage modulated and not current modulated? 4-20mA current loop is common for crane electronics, as are 24VDC digital. Most of these wired controls are simplistic and just have 24V parallel signals from the buttons that drive relays. There are also cranes where frequency inverters are controlled directly from remotes, but this doesn't look like it.

Comment: Now what you should do is to look in the other end - on the crane. What is the remote communicating with? A PLC? A crane overload limit switch? Something else?